# zookeeper zkCli.sh exits on fresh install

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I downloaded, ran `zkServer.sh start`, ran `ps -ef|grep zoo` to ensure it was running, then ran `zkCli.sh 127.0.0.1:2181`. The command exits back to the shell, with the following output (snipped to only show the end). Any ideas appreciated.

```
2013-01-12 14:11:04,318 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeper@438] - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=30000   watcher=org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain$MyWatcher@378f6235
ZooKeeper -server host:port cmd args
connect host:port
get path [watch]
ls path [watch]
set path data [version]
rmr path
delquota [-n|-b] path
quit 
printwatches on|off
create [-s] [-e] path data acl
stat path [watch]
close 
ls2 path [watch]
history 
listquota path
setAcl path acl
getAcl path
sync path
redo cmdno
addauth scheme auth
delete path [version]
setquota -n|-b val path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zkCli.sh` requires a `-server` flag as the message indicates:

```
-server host:port cmd args
```

Add in `-server` and you should be good:

```
zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181
```